# Use php array values for mysql insert query with implode function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

As I've found several ways to create array and insert it into the mysql query, I made a code below which obviously doesn't work. I pay attention on brackets and commas, but I missed something around VALUES.

Because, that is the part that is not working, the first part of the query (columns) is written properly (I think) but I got stuck with the second implode.

Please help.

```
$f_ids = array(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5);
$f_list = implode(',', $f_ids);

$val_ids = array($val[1],$val[2],$val[3],$val[4],$val[5]);
$val_list = implode("','", $val_ids);

$result = mysql_query("INSERT into mytable(id, title, {$val_list}) 
VALUES ('$id','$title','{$f_list}')");
```

Where is the error, I cannot find it???

Comment: For troubleshooting why don't you echo out the sql statement you are trying to build or echo the mysql error? Also you are using `$f_list` in the values, is that intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'{$f_list}'` is only *one value*. But `{$f_list}` is many column identifiers. The result is not enough values to be inserted (which `mysql_error()` would tell you if you used it).

What you want is:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT into mytable(id, title, {$f_list}) 
VALUES ('$id','$title','{$val_list}')");
```

Basically you just used the wrong variable.

Comment: Yes, thats the thing with the quotes. I made it work. You were right. Everything was fine, except the wrong variable :)

Comment: Thank you, hope this'll help someone else too

Answer (score 1):

Just quickly looking at your code, shouldn't be there

```
VALUES ('$id','$title','{$val_list}')
```

instead of

```
VALUES ('$id','$title','{$f_list}')
```

what you have there now?

Try to printout value of `$val_ids` and `$val_list` to see if values are as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON` instead of php arrays, that is so easy and error free way to insert mysql.

```
<?php
   $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
   echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

While executing, this will produce following result:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```